# Passing User input from mainactivity to a second activity in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-activity, user-input

I am bran new to this but I have successfully created a functional button. 
I am attempting to pass user input (editText1 on activity_main) to Recipe (my second activity) The first code is my functional button. What am I doing wrong in the second round of code in my attempt at passing information to be displayed on the second activity layout?

```
 package com.example.andrew;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){
               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recipe.class));
        }
        });
     }



     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
     }

  }
```

Second round of code: My attempt at passing information. First activity

```
package com.example.andrew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Edit Text et = (Edit Text) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         String theText =  et.getText().toString();
         Intent i = new Intent(this, Recipe.class);//Recipe is my second class
         i.putExtra("text_label", theText);//what is "text_label"? Where should it be?
         Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recipe.class));
        }
     });
   }

 }
```

And in my second activity I have:

```
 public class Recipe extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.recipe_layout);
         Intent i = getIntent();
         uriStringi = i.getStringExtra("text_label");//is text_label on actv. 1?
               startActivity(i);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding data in the intent but while starting the activity you are not using it. Instead creating new intent.

Solution:

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

Intent i = new Intent(this, Recipe.class);

i.putExtra("text_label", theText);

startActivity(i); // Write this in onClick()

Then in the Recipe, retrieve those values:

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {

```
String value = extras.getString("text_label");
```

}